# Launching Python scripts on Kotlin server for Android app?

Tags: python, android, kotlin

Tldr; how to launch python scripts for multiple clients at the same time using Kotlin server side code for Android clients.

I am developing an Android app using Kotlin for client side as well as server side code.
However, I want to use some libraries for NLP using Python. This is required for text input by any client on the phone, I need send that to the server for NLP processing and give result to the client accordingly.
Note that there can thousands of clients at a given time and my server should handle all the requests.
Should I use Ktor for handling multiple clients?
How to launch python code for each client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spent a long time to figure this out, but found a solution - https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/

Works for me like a charm.